# -(void) loadView with NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, loadview

```
- (void)loadView 
{
    [super loadView];
    arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"11.jpg",@"22.jpg",@"33.jpg", nil];       
    UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [awesomeView setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0]]];
    awesomeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:awesomeView]; 
    NSLog(@"%@",[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0]);
}
```

When I put the `NSMutableArray` in `-(void)viewDidLoad`, `UIImageView` displays nothing and `NSLog` shows NULL. Why is that?

ps. NSMutableArray worked perfectly in `-(void)loadView`. I've declared NSMutableArray *arrayOfImage in @interface .h file

Comment: Is your image view nil?

Comment: How to check if my image view is nil :p?

Comment: Either `NSLog()` it or use `po` in the debugger when you are stopped at a breakpoint you set in the method.

Comment: NSLog(@"%@",awesomeView); shows that my imageView is not nil :)

Comment: 1) Never call `super loadView` in the `loadView` method - see the docs for `UIViewController loadView`. 2) You need to assign `self.view` to a view you create in `loadView`. 3) As written, the code you have in `loadView` should actually be in `viewDidLoad`. You don't seem to need to implement `loadView`.

Comment: @maddy All true, but nothing would explain the "NULL" output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that the given could would output "NULL" in this situation is that `arrayOfImages` is `NULL` by itself.

This is only possible if `arrayOfImages` is declared as a weak variable.

But as @maddy pointed out, your code is all wrong: Don't call super, but assign `self.view`. Or use `viedDidLoad` instead (probably what you want here).

Comment: thank you:) I should learn deeper of LoadView and viewDidLoad.

Answer (score -1):

```
-(void)loadView 
{
   [super loadView];
    arrayOfImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"11.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"22.jpg"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"33.jpg"], nil];       
    UIImageView *awesomeView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)]; 
[awesomeView setImage :[UIImage imageNamed:[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0]]];
awesomeView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
[self.view addSubview:awesomeView]; 
NSLog(@"%@",[arrayOfImages objectAtIndex:0]);
```

This will work but you will only get to see 1 picture. ie the picture in the 0 index of the array.

If you want to show all then you got to apply a loop.

Comment: What is different in the code you post and the code the OP posted?

Comment: before giving a downvote please check the answer properly.
OP posted the code along with the names of the Image .
So the Array only contains strings NOT images.

[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.extension"]; this was my change.